# Truffle ganache fork

Tags: web3js, truffle, nodejs, ganache, ganache-cli

Suppose I have access to a full archive Node and I want to fork from a specific block using Ganache.

Using `ganache-cli`, I can specify where to fork using the `--fork` parameter
by passing it the Node access point and appending the block number after the symbol `@`.
For example if I want to fork from the block 11267664:

```
ganache-cli --fork=http://myNode@11267664
```

My question is:  are the transactions mined inside the block 11267664 included that fork or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the transactions mined inside block `11267664` are included in your fork. The word "from" in the ganache implies that this block is mined and *then* the fork happens:

> You can optionally specify the block to fork from using an @ sign: http://localhost:8545@1599200.